# Отступы у текста firefox

Tags: отступы, firefox, css

> Первая строка
>
> Вторая строка
>
> Третья строка

В firefox делаются большие   отступы между строками. Можно ли задать свои, посредством css?

Comment: сброс стилей используете?

Comment: а также padding-top, padding-bottom, margin-top, margin-bottom, line-height, height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

свойство  line-height: % или pt или еденицы например 0.5